# PowerPoint Active.Presentation.Updatelinks not updating

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a presentation with chart links to an Excel file, I have this simple code in an Excel file that opens the linked file, opens the PP, updates and removes the links, saves and closes.  The issue with this code is that the links are not always updating.  When I run this from the VB editor it works fine but I have this run on a daily schedule (using Workbook_Open and Application.OnTime) and it will not update the links when automatically running each day.  All other aspects of the code run without issue and there are no errors.  Here is the code, appreciate any assistance.

```html
Private Sub Update_PP()
    
    Dim PPT As New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
    
    Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Data Files\Excel File.xlsb"
    
    PPT.Visible = msoTrue
    PPT.Presentations.Open "C:\Data Files\Template.pptx", ReadOnly:=msoFalse, WithWindow:=msoTrue
    PPT.ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
    
    For Each sld In PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                shp.LinkFormat.BreakLink
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld

    PPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Data Files\New Template.pptx"
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Close
    PPT.Quit
    Set PPT = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I/O operations often take more time than your code allows. The fact that this runs correctly in the VBE is confirmation of this. Search on the terms _Wait_, _Sleep_ and _DoEvents_ to find many pages with solutions.

Comment: Thank you, tried DoEvents and others with no effect.  The entire code runs but the  links are not updated unless I open the workbook and run the macro manually.  What could possibly be causing the links not to update?